# Get the column's data in procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a procedure in SQL Server and I need to extract columns of that respected table. I extracted the column_name but when I used inside the cursor the statement:

```
select distinct @column_name from AogerCnlyOi.dbo.CnlyOiDealAnalysis
```

Here I need the data containing inside the column. But I get the name of column in the output.

```
USE AogerCnlyOi
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO


    create PROCEDURE [dbo].[QC_Actian_SSIS] AS
    
    DECLARE @column_name VarChar(MAX)
    declare @data_type VarChar(MAX)
    
    
    BEGIN
    
    Declare cur_tracking CURSOR FOR
    select column_name,data_type from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='CnlyOiDealAnalysis' order by ordinal_position
    
    OPEN cur_tracking;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_tracking INTO @column_name,@data_type;
    WHILE @@Fetch_status=0
    begin
    
    select distinct @column_name from AogerCnlyOi.dbo.CnlyOiDealAnalysis
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_tracking INTO @column_name,@data_type;
    END;
    CLOSE cur_tracking;
    DeAllocate cur_tracking;
    
    END 
    Go
```

Suppose my first column name was `"AuditGroup"` then I need the data inside the `"AuditGroup"` while using:

```
select distinct @column_name from AogerCnlyOi.dbo.CnlyOiDealAnalysis
```

but I am getting output as:

[image]

Since AuditGroup is the column name I need the data of Auditgroup. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you will need to use dynamic query [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: This feels like an [xy problem](//xyproblem.info) if I am honset. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Squirrel yes it worked thank you. please put separate ans so i can tick